# jQuery draggable item is changing the href of the page when dropped into "trash"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a pretty simple jQuery draggable/sortable/droppable combination going on where I'm sorting several divs, each of which contain an image wrapped in an anchor element with an href.

The problem is, when I drag a sortable item to the "trash" droppable area (to destroy it), the page sometimes changes its location and goes to the href URL from within the draggable!

I have debugged the hell out of the page and it is not any of my code causing this. The drop event happens normally and returns (I've tried returning true and false) just fine. It's something in jQuery UI's code causing the href to be fired.

It doesn't happen every time. I'm not "clicking" the element - just dragging.

Can anyone offer a suggestion please?

Example of my droppable code:

```
var trash = this._area_trash.droppable({
    drop: this.eventtrashDrop,
    hoverClass: 'highlight'
});

// ...

this.eventtrashDrop = function(event,ui) {
    var o = ui.draggable;
    if( typeof(o)=='object' && o!=null ) {
        if( o.parents(obj._selector_stack_area).length>0 ) {
            var id = parseInt(o.attr('lang'));
            o.remove();
            obj.eventStateRemove(id);
        }
    }
    // Page location hasn't been changed yet!
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT:** the original issue still remains, and I suspect it's some kind of bug in jQuery UI. However a workaround is to replace the anchor element with a div before destroying the sortable item so it can't change to the anchor's href:

```
        var anchor = jQuery(o).find("a");
        var img    = jQuery(anchor).html();
        jQuery(anchor).replaceWith("<div/>").html(img);
```

Comment: u may have to replicate the problem using jsfiddle.net..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the anchor is being triggered on the click.
You need to listen for event and prevent the default action.
Something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: No worries, I couldn't see it in your example code which is why I suggested it.